Calculation of solar eclipse progress based on time and location
I have a problem with the calculation of eclipse progress based on time.
I found somewhat an opposite query here:
Plotting the progress of an eclipse
in my situation, I want to visualize how the eclipse obscuration changes as the Sun changes its altitude. I currently have computations regarding changes in the solar altitude against the time, which is different for various latitudes.

The chart below shows the situation under normal conditions. On your Y axis, you see the LUX value, on the X axis you can see the altitude of the Sun.
The data I've picked up from this table:
Calculation of twilight sky surface brightness based on object's apparent magnitude
Now I am wondering of how could I have quite a quick calculation of the eclipse impact, taking into account the obscuration changes over the specific amount of time, which is determined by the solar altitude changes by 0,5 degrees.


In the images below we can see how Stellarium calculates it. This is pretty much what I would like to have. In fact, Stellarium won't do it automatically for me.
Is there any opportunity for calculations such as this? Where could I find the formula? I assume, the eclipse circumstances for the given altitude would be needed definitely and the day length also.

These computations are generally done using Besselian Elements, here are some resources:
A Manual of Spherical and Practical Astronomy - Chauvenet 1863,
The Mathematical Theory of Eclipses According to Chauvenet's Transformation of Bessel's Method - Buchanan 1904,
Explanatory Supplement to the Astronomical Ephemeris 1961,
Explanatory Supplement to the Astronomical Almanac 1992,
Elements of Solar Eclipses - Meeus 1989,
Prediction and Analysis of Solar Eclipse Circumstances - Williams 1971,
Actual implementation in JavaScript: https://github.com/gmiller123456/solareclipseviewer
